# Accessing Polymer's CSS

Tags: css, sass, polymer

I have problems accessing a Polymer defined CSS variable in a Jekyll SCSS/CSS file. Polymer Elements "Paper Styles" for colors is integrated via

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-styles/color.html">
```

in the `<head>` of my template. See https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles. For example, In the styles of [color.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/color.html), Polymer defines "--google-red-100: #f4c7c3;"

**Question:** Say I created an *.scss file in my Jekyll project. Is there any way to refer to this Polymer-defined color variable?

```
color: --google-red-100;
color: $--google-red-100;
color: $google-red-100;
color: var(--google-red-100);
```

does not work. If possible, I want to avoid putting another `<style>` definition into my document's head or to re-define color variables myself again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your CSS into a style module and then import it and refer to it within your components `<template>` tag like

```
<style import="my-style-module">
```

or in your head

```
<style is="custom-style" import="my-style-module">
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules for more details.